# Using a Thymeleaf form to construct POST request

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm having trouble passing form input to an attribute of a nested object (`object.subobject.property`). Specifically I have an `Institution institution` object which contains a `Country country` object which has an attribute called `countryName`, accessed like `institution.country.getCountryName()` but I cannot get the `Model` to populated correctly upon form submission. Below I have three print statements during the `@PostMapping`. That output looks like:

```
Institution(instId=398, instName=Alfred Wegener Institute for Polar and Marine Research, abbrvName=AWI, country=null, action=finish institution edit)
{modelinstitution=Institution(instId=398, instName=Alfred Wegener Institute for Polar and Marine Research, abbrvName=AWI, country=null, action=finish institution edit), org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.modelinstitution=org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors}
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors
```

Notice how the values for `country=` are `null` in both the `Model` and the `institutionAttributes` object. I was expecting something more like

```
country=Country(countryName=United States, countryId=12, parentCountry=)
```

**Why is the form not populating the `Country` object and how can I make it do so?**

I have a form:

```
<form id="lead_form" data-toggle="validator" th:action="@{/institutions}" th:object="${institution}" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="finish institution edit"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="instId" name="instId" th:value="${institution.instId}"/>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 text-left">
            <label for="instIdDisplay" class="control-label">Institution ID: </label>
            <input class="form-control border-input" th:value="${institution.instId}" id="instIdDisplay" name="instIdDisplay" type="number" disabled="true"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 text-left">
            <label for="instName" class="control-label">Institution Name: </label>
            <input class="form-control border-input" th:value="${institution.instName}" placeholder="Required" id="instName" name="instName" type="text" required="true"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-left">
            <label for="abbrvName" class="control-label">Abbreviation: </label>
            <input class="form-control border-input" th:value="${institution.abbrvName}" placeholder="Optional" id="abbrvName" name="abbrvName" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 text-left">
            <label for="countryName" class="control-label">Country: </label>
            <input class="form-control border-input" th:value="${institution.country.countryName}" placeholder="Required" id="countryName" name="countryName" type="text"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" align="left">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Save &amp; Close</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"/>
        <div class="col-md-4" align="right">
        <!--<input id="form_button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit" value="Save And Close"/>-->
            <a th:href="@{/institutions}" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

which issues a POST request from the controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "")
String institutionsEditPOST(
        @ModelAttribute("modelinstitution") Institution institutionAttributes, 
        Model model, 
        BindingResult result) {
    System.out.println(institutionAttributes);
    System.out.println(model);
    System.out.println(result);
    String newAction;
    String action = institutionAttributes.getAction();

    System.out.println("ENTER INSTITUTION POST BEFORE ACTION: "+action);

    String instName = institutionAttributes.getInstName();
    String abbrvName = institutionAttributes.getAbbrvName();
    String countryName = institutionAttributes.getCountry().getCountryName();

    model.addAttribute("instName", instName);
    model.addAttribute("abbrvName", abbrvName);
    model.addAttribute("countryName", countryName);

    newAction = "institutions";

    return "forms/fragments/"+newAction;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why your code is not working: You have `name="countryName"` but the countryName is not property of institution, but of country. You must provide path to the property: `name="country.countryName"`. But instead I suggest to use the convenient `th:field`.

Try this:

```xml
<input class="form-control border-input" th:field="*{country.countryName}" placeholder="Required" id="countryName" type="text"/>
```

It should properly set both `name` and `value` attributes (and also `id`). It normally saves you from specifying (Thymeleaf) attributes for these individually.

The `th:field` value must a selection expression (`*`) relative to the object specified in `th:object`.

Comment: Cool beans. That appears to work. Could you expand your answer to describe the different behaviors of `th:field` and `th:value`? Also, I read somewhere that `th:id`, `th:value`, `th:name` can be substituted for just `th:field`. True?

Comment: @medley56 Yes, `th:field` is pretty much a 3-for-1 deal. Expanded answer a bit.